# The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){}, String)

Tags: java, swing, awt, joptionpane, showmodaldialog

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUIClass extends JFrame {


    public static void main (String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame fm = new JFrame();
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        JButton butn = new JButton("Click ME");      
        tf.setBounds(50, 20, 130, 40);
        butn.setBounds(50, 80, 120, 30);
        butn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tf.getText());
        }
        });
        fm.add(tf);
        fm.add(butn);
        fm.setLayout(null);
        fm.setVisible(true);
        fm.setSize(400, 300);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem lies within...

```
butn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tf.getText());
    }
});
```

`this`, in this context, refers to the anonymous instance of the `ActionListener`, not the parent class.

A simple solution might be to use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf, tf.getText());`

Comment: thanks :* you are love buddy 
kindly help me in learning java

Answer (score 2):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tf.getText());
```

"this" refers to the ActionListener.

You want the frame to be the parent of the option pane:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fm, tf.getText());
```

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @AdilKhan, works fine for me. Read the API. You need to specify a component as the parent. A frame is a component. Maybe you are using an old compiler and you need to make the frame final. The point is the option pane is centered over the component you specify. It probably makes sense to use the frame?